# Compiling C code, does not see a #define'd constant

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I am trying to compile a 8hz mp3 encoder - C code in QT Creator.

In a file l3psy.c that starts like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "types.h"
#include "error.h"
#include "layer3.h"
#include "l3psy.h"

#include "fft.h"
#include "tables.h"
```

The build step complains about PI being undeclared here

```
for(i=0;i<BLKSIZE;i++)  window[i]  = 0.5*(1-cos(2.0*PI*(i-0.5)/BLKSIZE));
```

But types.h, which is obviously included, starts like this:

```
#ifndef TYPES_H
#define TYPES_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "portableio.h"


#ifdef PI
#undef PI
#define         PI                      3.14159265358979
#endif

#define         PI4                     .78539816339745
#define         PI64                    .049087385212
```

therefore, there is no way for PI to be undeclared.

What can be the problem here?

---

also, aside from that stopper, I also get complains about "implicit declaration of function abort" and "implicit declaration of function exit" and "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit'", but, they are standard functions of c, why would it complain?

Comment: Please post the actual error message you are getting.

Comment: "there is no way for PI to be undeclared": The way it is written, if `PI` is not defined before including types.h, then it remains not defined after inclusion.

Comment: oh... i see the mistake. it only executes if pi is defined.

Comment: okay, i did change the pi definition to "#ifdef PI #undef PI #endif #define         PI                      3.14159265358979

Comment: Why don't you use `M_PI` from `math.h`?

Comment: That is not my code, that is a code of an open source mp3 encoder from 8hz, i dont know why didnt they use it, i guess for crossplatformness or to maintain constant results (not rely on different precision of PI in different systems?)

Comment: @larsmans: `M_PI` and friends are specified by Posix, not C or C++.  I guess this code wants to be portable beyond Posix... though it would probably be worth #including _<math.h>_ and defining their `PI` in terms of `M_PI` if it's available.

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem, about `PI`, see Pascal Cuoq's comment (that's all).

For the problems with implicit declarations being reported, you haven't included the relevant header(s) for those functions. IIRC `exit` and `abort` are declared by `<stdlib.h`. But check it out.

Cheers & hth.,